# Modernizr.mq in vanilla JS

Tags: javascript, dependencies, modernizr

I'm trying to get rid of Modernizr in my project but I can't seem to understand or find a replacement for the .mq function. Can someone explain or provide a bare solution to my problem?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

According to the [Modernizr docs](https://modernizr.com/docs#modernizr-mq), `mq` checks whether the page current matches a media query you pass it, e.g. `if (Modernizr.mq('(min-width: 900px)'))` to test if the window is at least 900px wide.

On vaguely-modern browsers (IE10+, [details here](http://caniuse.com/#feat=matchmedia)), you can use [`window.matchMedia`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Window/matchMedia) to do that. Example from that page:

```
if (window.matchMedia("(min-width: 400px)").matches) {
  /* the viewport is at least 400 pixels wide */
} else {
  /* the viewport is less than 400 pixels wide */
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Modernizr is open source - you can see exactly what it does [here](https://github.com/Modernizr/Modernizr/blob/master/src/mq.js).

In modern browsers, it will almost always just be window.matchMedia